# MSI motherboard not booting to BIOS

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, bios

Good evening. I am using an MSI motherboard running Windows 10. I cannot boot into the bios by using the del key on my keyboard. Whenever I use it, my computer will usually flash up "Entering Setup..." In the bottom left hand corner, yet it never actually loads the bios and leaves me with a black screen. I believed this was because I was running my monitor from my graphics card HDMI port, but when I plug my monitor into my mobo HDMI port, I don't get any feedback. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Model number MS7681VER4.0

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried it yet, you may want to reset the BIOS settings. This is usually done via a shunt on the systemboard, but I cannot tell you exactly how since I do not know the model number of your 'board. Your problem sounds like it might be the BIOS settings are corrupted.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that tommorow.

Comment: It's an MS7681VER4.0

Comment: Instructions for it are on page 2-21 of the user manual, which you can get here: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z68AGD65_B3.html#down-manual

Comment: Hi, KA. Sorry I'm a little bit late, but the problem was with my graphics card. Removing it allowed me to enter the BIOS settings. However, my version of Windows 10 has recently just thrown up a driver error on boot, and I can't change to boot from USB without taking the graphics card out of my pc. Any suggestions to get the BIOS to display on the graphics card? (EVGA GTX 970)

Comment: Do you have another video card you can use to install Windows 10, and then switch over to your GTX 970 after install? Or would that interfere with activation?

Comment: I'm not installing windows 10, I'm repairing the current version I have. I am unable to get to the BIOS when I have my graphics card installed. I just remove the graphics card and then use the one on the motherboard and I can see it fine. Is there a way to make it do this with the graphics card still installed?

Comment: Oops I misunderstood.